# how to use vscode to debug go 1.11.x

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am new to golang, but working on go 1.11.x.

My team use `go module`. The first time I clone the repository, I need to run `GO111MODULE=on go mod download` to download dependencies modules.

Then I need to run `GO111MODULE=on go run main.go` to run my app.

There is no one use vscode debugger, they prefer console log instead.

Is there any way to debug go 1.11.x using vscode?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, vscode debugger UI supports the Go debugger (delve). Have you installed the Go plugin for VS Code? If so, you just use the normal debugging functions in VS Code to debug your project.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian for the response, and what about `GO111MODULE=on`, I try to set it on env section but it does not work?

Can you please show me the working launch.json file for go 1.11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause right now. It is the source code of my team, not related to vscode or go 1.11.

My working launch.json is here

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Go debug",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.go",
            "env": {
            //   "GO111MODULE": "on"
            },
            "args": [],
            "showLog": true
        }
    ]
}
```